# Reason for the text converting from "ZZ" to "1" when i try to add "ZZ"+1

Tags: string, perl, concatenation

**I just want to know the reason if i use the (.) instead i got the result but + is doing arhtematic addition but how is that ASCII addition**

```
 my $string = "ZZ";
 my $appendstring = $string+1;
 print $appendstring;
```

**output**

```
1
```

**Expeccting**

```
ZZ1
```

Comment: I don't believe that that output corresponds to that code.

Comment: @mob sorry  i did not check that

Answer (score 3):

First of all, your question is very unclear, and your "example" (if you want to call it that) does not match reality, but in an effort to help whoever stumbles across this question in the future, I'm going to venture an answer anyway.

Let's clear up your example first:

```
$ perl -lwe '$x = "ZZ"; print $x + 1;'
Argument "ZZ" isn't numeric in addition (+) at -e line 1.
1
```

What I *think* you might have meant was:

```
$ perl -lwe '$x = "ZZ"; print ++$x;'
AAA
```

And the reason for that is explained in [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Auto-increment-and-Auto-decrement):

> The auto-increment operator has a little extra builtin magic to it. If
>   you increment a variable that is numeric, or that has ever been used
>   in a numeric context, you get a normal increment. If, however, the
>   variable has been used in only string contexts since it was set, and
>   has a value that is not the empty string and matches the pattern
>   `/^[a-zA-Z]*[0-9]*\z/`, the increment is done as a string, preserving
>   each character within its range, with carry.

---

Edit: your updated question isn't any clearer than your original question, but now I think you're asking about string concatenation, which means you want the [string concatenation operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Additive-Operators): `.`

```
$ perl -lwe '$x = "ZZ"; print $x . 1;'
ZZ1
```

There is, however, a special case where you can use a string with the numeric addition operator and not generate a warning:

```
$ perl -lwe '$x = "0 but true"; print $x + 1;'
1
```

You also mentioned "ASCII addition", but I have no idea what that is or what you mean by that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer i have been for @Matt Jacob

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](http://perlmaven.com/automatic-value-conversion-or-casting-in-perl)

this is the way to concatenate

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $x = "4T";
my $y = 3;
print $x . $y;    # 4T3
```

but if you do this:

```
print $x + $y;  # 7
                # Argument "4T" isn't numeric in addition (+) at ...
```

Whenever you use the "+" perl tries to convert both values to numeric, if you provide a string and a number or 2 strings it'll take these as 0 and sum them.
http://ideone.com/0LyEij

Comment: ya thanks for the answer.I tried using (.) concatenation  but i want to know what is happening in the behind

Comment: If you read the link i provided it states that whenever you use a "+" sign it tries to do a numerical addition trying to convert both values to numeric.

Comment: also the output is 1 not ZZa according to the perl fiddle.